# i want to upload video from gallery in ios using titanium,Please guide me to solve this and upload the video successfully

Tags: titanium, appcelerator-titanium

[image]

> **// i have done the following code on the button click but when i
>   click on the choose button the screen gets stuck on this screen
>   only.**

```
btnGallery.addEventListener('click', function() {
    Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery({
        mediaTypes : [![enter image description here][1]][1][Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO], *//to select video*
        success : function(event) {
                    var result=event.media;   *//Store video in blob form*
                    Ti.API.info(event);
                    var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
                    xhr.onload = function(e) {
                                    Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
                                                title : 'Success',
                                                message : 'status code ' + this.status
                                            }).show();
                                        };
                    xhr.open('POST', 'http://videorequestlive.com/upload_videos');
                    xhr.send({video : event.media,uploadedby : Ti.App.Properties.getString('loginProfileId'),requested_video_description : rowChildren[1].text,requested_video_id : rowChildren[3].text,requestedby : rowChildren[4].text,requested_video_title : 'User',});
                                    },
                                });
```

Comment: What is exactly your problem? what kind of errors do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Your mediaTypes seems to be broken

Try this:

```
btnGallery.addEventListener('click', function() {
Ti.Media.openPhotoGallery({
    mediaTypes : [Ti.Media.MEDIA_TYPE_VIDEO], *//to select video*
    success : function(event) {
                var result=event.media;   *//Store video in blob form*
                Ti.API.info(event);
                var xhr = Titanium.Network.createHTTPClient();
                xhr.onload = function(e) {
                                Ti.UI.createAlertDialog({
                                            title : 'Success',
                                            message : 'status code ' + this.status
                                        }).show();
                                    };
                xhr.open('POST', 'http://videorequestlive.com/upload_videos');
                xhr.send({video : event.media,uploadedby : Ti.App.Properties.getString('loginProfileId'),requested_video_description : rowChildren[1].text,requested_video_id : rowChildren[3].text,requestedby : rowChildren[4].text,requested_video_title : 'User',});
                                },
                            });
```